# Python: How to find the string with most matches in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, rss, string-matching

I'll try to explain in detail what I need:

I'm parsing an RSS feed in Python using feedparser. This feed has, of course, a list of items, with title, link and description just like a common RSS feed.

In the other hand I have a list of strings with some keywords I need to find in the item's description.

What I need to do is **find the item which has the most keyword matches**

Example:

*RSS feed*

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>Lion</title>
        <link>...</link>
        <description>
            The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the four big cats in the genus 
            Panthera, and a member of the family Felidae.
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Panthera</title>
        <link>...</link>
        <description>
            Panthera is a genus of the Felidae (cats), which contains 
            four well-known living species: the tiger, the lion, the jaguar, and the leopard.
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Cat</title>
        <link>...</link>
        <description>
            The domestic cat is a small, usually furry, domesticated, 
            carnivorous mammal. It is often called the housecat, or simply the 
            cat when there is no need to distinguish it from other felids and felines.
        </description>
    </item>
</channel>
```

Keyword list

```
['cat', 'lion', 'panthera', 'family']
```

So in this case, the item with most (unique) matches is the first one, because it contains all 4 keywords (doesn't matter it says 'cats' instead of just 'cat', I just need to find the literal keyword inside the string)

Let me clarify that even if some description contained the 'cat' keyword 100 times (and none of the other keywords), this will not be the winner, because I'm looking for the most keywords contained, not the most times a keyword appears.

Right now, I'm looping over the rss items and doing it "manually", counting the times a keyword appears (but I'm having the problem mentioned in the above paragraph).

I'm very new at Python and I come from a different kind of language (C#), so I'm sorry if this is pretty trivial.

**How would you approach to this problem?**

Comment: The answers below are all great, but beware partial matches (does `concatenate` count as an occurrence of `cat`?) and capitalisation (does `Cat` count as a match? how about `CAT`?)

Comment: Yes, for now 'concatenate' count as an ocurrence of 'cat' and doesn't have to be case-sensitive. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
texts = [ "The lion (Panthera leo) ...", "Panthera ...", "..." ]
keywords  = ['cat', 'lion', 'panthera', 'family']

# gives the count of `word in text`
def matches(text):
    return sum(word in text.lower() for word in keywords)

# or inline that helper function as a lambda:
# matches = lambda text:sum(word in text.lower() for word in keywords)

# print the one with the highest count of matches
print max(texts, key=matches)
```

Comment: Amazing solution. Would you mind explaining a little how this code works? I'm now reading about lambda in Python.

Comment: There is a conversion to lowercase missing.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, you're right, I've just replaced the 'texts' argument in the max function for: `[x.lower() for x in texts]`

Comment: @emzero: You could also do `sum(word in text.lower() for word in keywords)`

Comment: @NiklasB. Right, nicer because it prints the original string, not the lower-cased one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are very elegant, but perhaps too simple for the real world. Some ways in which they might break include:

- Partial word matching - should 'cat' match 'concatenate'? How about 'cats'?
- Case sensitivity - should 'cat' match 'CAT'? how about 'Cat'?

My solution below allows for both of these cases.

```
import re

test_text = """
Cat?

The domestic cat is a small, usually furry, domesticated, 
carnivorous mammal. It is often called the housecat, or simply the 
cat when there is no need to distinguish it from other felids and felines.
"""

wordlist = ['cat','lion','feline']
# Construct regexp like r'\W(cat|lionfeline)s?\W'
# Matches cat, lion or feline as a whole word ('cat' matches, 'concatenate'
# does not match)
# also allow for an optional trailing 's', so that both 'cat' and 'cats' will
# match.
wordlist_re = r'\W(' + '|'.join(wordlist) + r')(s?)\W'

# Get list of all matches from text. re.I means "case insensitive".
matches = re.findall(wordlist_re, test_text, re.I)

# Build list of matched words. the `[0]` means first capture group of the regexp
matched_words = [ match[0].lower() for match in matches]

# See which words occurred
unique_matched_words = [word for word in wordlist if word in matched_words]

# Count unique words
num_unique_matched_words = len(unique_matched_words)
```

The output is like:

```
>>> wordlist_re
'\\W(cat|lion|feline)(s?)\\W'
>>> matches
[('Cat', ''), ('cat', ''), ('cat', ''), ('feline', 's')]
>>> matched_words
['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'feline']
>>> unique_matched_words
['cat', 'feline']
>>> num_unique_matched_words
2
>>>
```

Comment: According to the question, partial matches are okay and the search should be case-insensitive.

Comment: Sidenote: case-insensitive regexps are sometimes a bad idea (they can sometimes be slow due to backtracking.) You can `lower()` the entire string first, but beware unicode strings (what is `'Главное в новостях'.lower()`?)